# How to create a Zend project skeleton with Composer, under Windows

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, wamp, composer-php

After having a hard time (5 hours) with enabling **OpenSSL**, **Composer** and **Zend** in PHP under **Wamp** in Windows, I managed to get everything working besides fragmented information I have collected. \o/

Now I have one more challenge, related to this command which is not working because of some sort of malformed file from zendframework.com.

**The command:**

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12>php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-appli
cation c:\wamp\www\a_brand_new_site_with_zend
```

**The error:**

```
  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "http://packages.zendframework.com/packages.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:
  ×{    "packages": {
  ^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

[image]

I know the json file is arriving in bad shape but maybe I am missing something.

Any ideas how to get **Composer** working (or any other easy tool) to automatically create the **Zend** project files?

Answer (score 0):

So, the workaround for now is to download from **another** url.

Zendframework.com has some kind of problem.

[image]